# Centroid of a quadrilateral $ABCD$: $\overrightarrow{GA} + \overrightarrow{GB} + \overrightarrow{GC} + \overrightarrow{GD} = \overrightarrow{0}$

Tags: geometry, vectors, quadrilateral, centroid

Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral and let $G_1$, $G_2$, $G_3$, $G_4$ be he centroids of triangles $ABC$, $BCD$, $CDA$ and $DAB$, respectively. Assume without proof that $G_1G_3$ and $G_2G_4$ always intersect at a unique point $G$ (this can be shown by verifying that $\overrightarrow{G_1G_3}$ and $\overrightarrow{G_2G_4}$ are not collinear). Is it true that $\overrightarrow{GA} + \overrightarrow{GB} + \overrightarrow{GC} + \overrightarrow{GD} = \overrightarrow{0}$?

I am well aware of properties like $3\overrightarrow{GG_1} = \overrightarrow{GA} + \overrightarrow{GB} + \overrightarrow{GC}$ but I cannot find a way to combine them to show the above.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Huh?  $ABCD$ is planar so $G_i$ are coplanar, hence $\overrightarrow{G_1G_3}$ and $\overrightarrow{G_2G_4}$ are coplanar.  Do you mean parallel instead?

Comment: Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That property is false. Below you can find a counterexample: $G'$ is the unique point such that $\overrightarrow{G'A} + \overrightarrow{G'B} + \overrightarrow{G'C} + \overrightarrow{G'D} = \overrightarrow{0}$ (as you may easily check), but it is not the same as point $G$ as defined in the question.

[image]

The confusion might arise from the fact that the centroid of four points $ABCD$ ($G'$ in the figure) is not the same as the centroid of quadrilateral $ABCD$ (i.e. the centroid of its surface), which is in fact $G$. On the other hand, for a triangle both centroids are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an other counterexample. The involved points are (also identified with their affixes and with the corresponding vectors in $\Bbb R^2$):
$$
\begin{aligned}
A &= (-6,0)\ ,\\
B &= (0,-6)\ ,\\
C &= (12,0)\ ,\\
D &= (0, 18)\ ,\\[2mm]
G_1 &=\frac 13(A+B+C)=(2,-2)\ ,\\
G_2 &=\frac 13(B+C+D)=(4,4)\ ,\\
G_3 &=\frac 13(C+D+A)=(2,6)\ ,\\
G_4 &=\frac 13(D+A+B)=(-2,4)\ ,\\[2mm]
G &=(2,4)\ ,\\
A+B+C+D &= (6,12)\ ,\\
4G &=(8,16)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
In a picture:

[image: MSE stackexchange problem 3772166]

One more observation that may explain the difference.

Let $\Gamma$ be the centroid of $ABCD$. Then it is also the centroid of $G_1G_2G_3G_4$. So a counterexample to the vectorial relation
$$
4G\Gamma =GA+GB+GC+GD=0
$$
is obtained by choosing the points $A,B,C,D$ so that for the associated quadrilateral $G_1G_2G_3G_4$ the intersection of its  diagonals $G_1G_3$ and $G_2G_4$ is not its centroid.

Comment: Sorry, the site wanted me to log in again, but all mse opened tabs (including the one where i tried to insert the picture) were showing the gravatar, so i could by no means consider i am logged out... The picture is now inserted...